# ipywidgets dropdown onclick

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

It seems that there is no `on_click` option with dropdown widgets, I was wondering if there is some sort of workaround. One method I was thinking was, everytime an option is chosen, to flush the options and start the dropdown from the top again, where the top option would be the empty `""`.

For instance suppose I have:

```py
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

def dropdown_event_handler(change):
    print(change.new)
    # flush the options and start from "" again

options = ["", "A", "B"]
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=options, description="Categories")
dropdown.observe(dropdown_event_handler, names="value")
display(dropdown)
```

So the desired behaviour is that if I press "A" and "A" again, A would be printed out twice.

Comment: Buttons have an `on_click` method, but you don't click a Dropdown, you choose an option. 

Sounds like it would be better served by an array of `Buttons` for your different options?

Comment: I'm trying to build a text labeller. And the number of labels can be 100+ so probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suggested, you could set the value of the widget to `""` after each change:

```py
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

def dropdown_event_handler(change):
    print(change.new)
    dropdown.value = ""       

options = ["", "A", "B"]
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=options, description="Categories")
dropdown.observe(dropdown_event_handler, names='value')

display(dropdown)
```

And I fear that is your only option. The `Dropdown` widget has no other type than "change". You can see all available types by printing them with `type=All`.

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from traitlets import All

def dropdown_event_handler(change):
    print(change)    

options = ["", "A", "B"]
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=options, description="Categories")
dropdown.observe(dropdown_event_handler, type=All)

display(dropdown)
```

Output:

```
{'name': '_property_lock', 'old': traitlets.Undefined, 'new': {'index': 1}, 'owner': Dropdown(description='Categories', options=('', 'A', 'B'), value=''), 'type': 'change'}
{'name': 'label', 'old': '', 'new': 'A', 'owner': Dropdown(description='Categories', index=1, options=('', 'A', 'B'), value=''), 'type': 'change'}
{'name': 'value', 'old': '', 'new': 'A', 'owner': Dropdown(description='Categories', index=1, options=('', 'A', 'B'), value='A'), 'type': 'change'}
{'name': 'index', 'old': 0, 'new': 1, 'owner': Dropdown(description='Categories', index=1, options=('', 'A', 'B'), value='A'), 'type': 'change'}
{'name': '_property_lock', 'old': {'index': 1}, 'new': {}, 'owner': Dropdown(description='Categories', index=1, options=('', 'A', 'B'), value='A'), 'type': 'change'}
```

So you can't observe a value in a `Dropdown` widget if it did not change. For more information see the [Traitlets documentation](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#callbacks-when-trait-attributes-change).